# How to loop through array with objects inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

Actually its working with simple array

```
let box1 =[01, 02, 03];
function hitMiss(box) {
  $("td").on("click", function(){
      let y = $(this).attr("id");

          if (box.find(boxId => boxId == y)) {
              $(this).addClass("yes");
              console.log("full");
              } else {
              $(this).addClass("no");
              console.log("empty");
     }
  });
};
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjBgNK)

But i need to use objects in array

```
let boxes = [
    { locations: [01, 02, 03]},
    { locations: [23, 24, 25]},
    { locations: [41, 42, 43]}
];
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and explain what is wrong specifically.

Comment: Yes, what exactly have you tried yet with your array of objects? And what do you want to achieve? This is not quite clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate all the `locations` using `reduce` as

```
var allLocs = boxes.reduce( (a,c) => a.concat(c.locations), [])
```

Change your internal *if-condition* to

```
  if (allLocs.find(boxId => boxId == y)) 
  {
        $(this).addClass("yes");
        console.log("full");
  }
  else 
  {
        $(this).addClass("no");
        console.log("empty");
  }
```

Please find [updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RybKKK)

Answer (score 1):

## ES6

You can also use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). you can achieve your required result.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
boxes = boxes.reduce((r, {locations}) => [...r, ...locations], []);
```

**DEMO**

```js
let boxes = [{
  locations: [01, 02, 03]
}, {
  locations: [23, 24, 25]
}, {
  locations: [41, 42, 43]
}];

hitMiss(boxes);

function hitMiss(box) {
  box = box.reduce((r, {
    locations
  }) => [...r, ...locations], []);

  $("td").on("click", function() {
    let y = $(this).attr("id");

    if (box.some(boxId => boxId == y)) {
      $(this).addClass("yes");
      console.log("full");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("no");
      console.log("empty");
    }
  });
};
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #859cac;
}

table {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

td {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: black;
}

.yes {
  background-color: red;
}

.no {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="00">00</td>
    <td id="01">01</td>
    <td id="02">02</td>
    <td id="03"></td>
    <td id="04"></td>
    <td id="05"></td>
    <td id="06"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="10"></td>
    <td id="11"></td>
    <td id="12"></td>
    <td id="13"></td>
    <td id="14"></td>
    <td id="15"></td>
    <td id="16"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="20"></td>
    <td id="21"></td>
    <td id="22"></td>
    <td id="23"></td>
    <td id="24"></td>
    <td id="25"></td>
    <td id="26"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="30"></td>
    <td id="31"></td>
    <td id="32"></td>
    <td id="33"></td>
    <td id="34"></td>
    <td id="35"></td>
    <td id="36"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="40"></td>
    <td id="41"></td>
    <td id="42"></td>
    <td id="43"></td>
    <td id="44"></td>
    <td id="45"></td>
    <td id="46"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="50"></td>
    <td id="51"></td>
    <td id="52"></td>
    <td id="53"></td>
    <td id="54"></td>
    <td id="55"></td>
    <td id="56"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="60"></td>
    <td id="61"></td>
    <td id="62"></td>
    <td id="63"></td>
    <td id="64"></td>
    <td id="65"></td>
    <td id="66"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```